# How to iterate through an array in postman to change environment variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to to loop through a set of ids to change their title. `{{id}}` and `{{title}}`.

My request looks like this `{{app}}/data/{{id}}`

The body looks like this `{ "title": "{{title}}" }`

Here is my current test code that doesn't work but more or less what I'm working towards.

```
var ids = [1, 2, 3]
var titles = ["title1", "title2", "title3"]
var i = titles.length
for(var j = 0; j < i; j++){
     pm.environment.set("id",ids[j])
     pm.environment.set("title",titles[j])
     postman.setNextRequest("<request_name>")
}
```

My issue is that the title is only being updated the very last one title3 and ignoring the rest. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you run the request by runner or just sending the request?

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I tried both, neither worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `postman.setNextRequest` only works in runner.

Second, your task will be achieved using this code:

In tab Test of Request 1:

```
//Save 2 arrays
let ids = [1, 2, 3]
let titles = ["title1", "title2", "title3"]
pm.environment.set("ids", JSON.stringify(ids));
pm.environment.set("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
```

In tab Pre-request of Request 2:

```
let ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("ids"));
let titles = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("titles"));

pm.environment.set("id", ids.shift())
pm.environment.set("title", titles.shift())

pm.environment.set("ids", JSON.stringify(ids));
pm.environment.set("titles", JSON.stringify(titles));
```

In tab Test of Request 2:

```
let ids = JSON.parse(pm.environment.get("ids"));
if (ids.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest("New Request 69020616");
}
```

The result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based off of [@lucas-nguyen-17 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69032945/2249725) I did the same thing but made an array of tests and only used one request by using `pm.variables` instead of `pm.environment` so the variables are only local to the test and not the whole environment.

### Pre-request Script

```
let allTests = [
    { name: '1', statusCode: 200, data: {id: 1, title: 'title1'} },
    { name: '2', statusCode: 200, data: {id: 2, title: 'title2'} },
    { name: '3', statusCode: 200, data: {id: 3, title: 'title3'} },
    { name: "null id", statusCode: 400, data: {id: null} },
    { name: "happy", statusCode: 200, data: {} },
];
 
// Set test data on only first iteration in runner
if (pm.variables.get('testData') === undefined {
    pm.variables.set('testData', JSON.stringify(allTests));
}

// Get the current test and remove it from the test still needing to run
let testData = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get('testData'));
let currentTestData = testData.shift()
pm.variables.set('testData', JSON.stringify(testData))
pm.variables.set('currentTestData', JSON.stringify(currentTestData))

// Combine current test data with a happy object so all parts aren't needed on every test
let happy = {id: '0', title: 'title'};
let test = {
    ...happy,
    //overwrite happy with variables in test data
    ...currentTestData.data 
};

// Set the variables for the test
pm.variables.set('id', test.id);
pm.variables.set('title', test.title);
```

### Tests

```
let test = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get('currentTestData'));

pm.test(`Test(${test.name}) Status code is ${test.statusCode}`, function () {
    pm.response.to.have.status(test.statusCode);
});

// Run the next test if any are left
let testData = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get('testData'));
if (testData.length > 0){
    postman.setNextRequest(pm.info.requestName);
}
```

When not using the runner this will always just run the first test case but using the runner runs them all.

Answer (score 0):

Create a json file like below:

```
[
    {"ids": "1","title":"title1"},
    {"ids": "2","title":"title2"},
    {"ids": "3","title":"title2"}
]
```

Then run your PUT query from collection, click run, and select file (your json) file and then run new collection copy.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).